# How to get SOAP URI from WSDL?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm testing a SOAP webservice and I want to use it in non-wsdl mode.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null,
[
    'location' => 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx',
    'uri' => 'http://tempuri.org/',
    'trace' => 1,
]);

echo $argv[1].' - '.$argv[2].' = '. $client->Subtract(
    [
        'intA' => $argv[2],
        'intB' => $argv[1]
    ])->SubtractResult.PHP_EOL;
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/#Subtract.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

When I use it in WSDL mode it works fine...

I got the idea of using `http://tempuri.org/` as URI from the definition of the WS:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

But apparently that's not it... any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Try throwing `'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2` into the array for the second set of options to the constructor

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas! That seems like a good idea, I'll give it a try and comment